# How do we mock generated protobufs in moq that have properties that do not use interfaces?

Tags: c#, microservices, protocol-buffers, moq, grpc

### Background

I am using google's protobuf generator to convert my protos to C# objects. Unfortunately, the generated objects are `sealed partial` classes. I need to use the proto objects directly in my existing codebase. I have already extracted these classes to interfaces, but I am now having trouble converting the interfaces to the objects that have implement them (examples below). Since the properties are coming in as actual object properties rather than interface properties (`IObject Property` vs `Object Property`), I need to return actual objects in my moq setups.

### What I've Tried

1. I have tried casting the `mock.Object` as an object
   (`(Object)iObjectMock.Object`) which results in an
   `InvalidCastException`.
2. I have tried mocking using an actual object instead of an interface,
   but Moq is unable to mock sealed classes (which is what proto
   generation makes).
3. I have tried using the `[ProtoContract]` attribute from
   `protobuf-net` to try to override the classes that were generated by
   the protobufgenerator. They don't work together.

### Example Code

#### Protos

Foo.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
 
    string TheBiggerFoo = 1

    string FooStuff = 2

}
```

Bar.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "Foo.proto";


message Bar {
 
    Foo TheFoo = 1

    string TheBigBar = 2

}
```

#### Protobuf Generated Classes

Foo.cs

```
public partial sealed class Foo {
    public string TheBiggerFoo { get; set; } // shorthand that is done the "long way" in the actual generated object
    public string FooStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Bar.cs

```
public partial sealed class Bar {
    public Foo TheFoo { get; set; }
    public string TheBigBar { get; set; }
}
```

#### My code

IFoo.cs

```
public interface IFoo {
    string TheBiggerFoo { get; set; }
    string FooStuff { get; set; }
}
```

IBar.cs

```
public interface IBar {
    Foo TheFoo { get; set; }
    string TheBigBar { get; set; }
}
```

Foo.cs

```
public partial class Foo : IFoo {

}
```

Bar.cs

```
public partial class Bar : IBar {

}
```

#### Classes made for tests

DoTheThing.cs

```
public class DoTheThing {

    public IBar TheThing;

    public DoTheThing(IBar theThing){
        this.TheThing = theThing;
    }

    public string DidTheThing(){
        var output = "I did the thing: ";
        output += TheThing.TheFoo.TheBiggerFoo + " ";
        output += TheThing.TheFoo.FooStuff + " ";
        output += TheThing.TheBigBar;

        return output;
    }
}
```

DoTheThingTests.cs

```
public class DoTheThingTests{

    [Fact]
    public void DidTheThingTest(){
        // Arrange

        var biggerFoo = "I Am The Bigger Foo";
        var fooStuff = "I am foo stuff";
        var bigBar = "I am the big bar";

        var mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
        mockFoo.Setup(x => x.TheBiggerFoo).Returns(biggerFoo);
        mockFoo.Setup(x => x.FooStuff).Returns(fooStuff);

        var mockBar = new Mock<IBar>();
        mockBar.Setup(x => x.TheFoo).Returns((Foo)mockFoo.Object); // Doesnt work and throws exception (using `as` just makes the mock return as null)
        mockBar.Setup(x => x.BigBar).Returns(bigBar);

        var doTheThing = new DoTheThing(mockBar.Object);

        var expected = "I did the thing: " + biggerFoo + " " + fooStuff + " " + bigBar;

        // Act

        var actual = doTheThing.DidTheThing();


        // Assert

        Assert.Equals(actual, expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you are complicating things there. Why do you need mock at all? Simply instantiate your data objects!

Comment: Sorry but it is unclear for me that do you have any problem when you try to mock the `IFoo` and `IBar` interfaces?

Comment: @PeterCsala I am able to mock `IFoo`, but when I try to mock `IBar` and set up the `TheFoo` property, I get a casting exception because in the `Returns()` method, I am casting the interface (the object returned by the `IFoo` mock) to an actual `Foo` object.

Comment: @jalepi Isnt that bad practice? If `Foo` had a public method that was used in the method under test and the `FooMethod` broke, that would make my test fail (making my unit test "invalid"). In my case, it is unlikely. It should work fine though, I just want to make sure I am following best practices.

Comment: @DaDuStMaN20 Can you change your `IBar` interface in a way that the `TheFoo` property is `IFoo` rather than `Foo`?

Comment: @PeterCsala Nope because then `Bar` will not implement the `IBar` interface. The properties are generated by the protobuf generator in the sealed class automatically (so I dont have access to change them).

Comment: @DaDuStMaN20 It does implement `IBar` since `Bar` is defined as `partial` and you explicitly stated that inside your partial class definition.

Comment: @PeterCsala I cant do that because I have no access to the sealed partial. The files (sealed partial classes) are automatically generated at build-time (without paying any attention to the existing classes/files). If I put `IBar TheFoo` in the partial that isnt generated, it will throw a compile error saying that `TheFoo` is already a property. If I am misunderstanding something, please let me know, but that is my experience in this scenario.

Comment: @DaDuStMaN20 You are correct, my fault sorry

Comment: @DaDuStMaN20, a bad practice is certainly using generated code throughout your application. Better is mapping those proto objects into your own types instead.

Comment: @jalepi I have a codebase that is rather large that relies a lot on these protos (and the generated objects). I cannot change all of these objects to not be generated all at once. I do however need to work with what I have for now and generate unit tests. As per this issue, do you have any suggestions outside of not using mocks and using actual objects? I just want to make sure I am barking up the correct tree.

Comment: Your generated proto classes in C# are basically POCO, their intent is just holding data. I see no reason for mocking them, as you can simply instantiate them directly, unless you really want to spy on them, making sure members are called or even counting those calls. That is not a bad practice, IMHO.